# Си неопределенное поведение

Tags: c

Как получается что когда я печатаю строку то все окей
обращаюсь к первому символу - тоже
а дальше неизвестные символы

```
 16 char    get_format(const char **str)
 17 {
 18     if (!*str)
 19         return (0);
 20     ft_putstr((char *)*str);
 21     ft_putchar('\n');
 22     ft_putchar((char)*str[0]);
 23     ft_putchar('\n');
 24     ft_putchar((char)*str[1]);
 25     ft_putchar('\n');
```

вывод:

```
%*.*sqwe%-s
%
�
```

Comment: код под цифрой 2 рядом с изображением
не знаю почему показывается только 1 картинка

Comment: Приоритеты операторов! `ft_putchar((char)(*str)[1]);`

Comment: Да спасибо это работает, а что если я захочу использовать безиндексное итерирование, как тогда буде верно написать? (**str)?

Comment: Вывод `i`-го символа: `ft_putchar(*(*str+i));`

Answer (score 1):

Правильно вот так вызывать `ft_putchar((char)(*str)[0]);` и `ft_putchar((char)(*str)[1]);`.